# Using framebuffer device as a normal display (USB to HDMI adapter) on Linux

Tags: linux, framebuffer, xorg, hdmi

I have a USB3 to HDMI adapter based on UFX7000 SMSC chipset. It has a driver in the Linux kernel, but it makes a framebuffer device:

```
usb 2-1.1.1: SMSC UDX USB device /dev/fb1 attached. 800x600 resolution. Using 940K framebuffer memory
```

Is there an easy way to use that fb1? xrandr won't see what's attached to it, so it's either making a fixed multi-display fixed x.org config or maybe (is that possible?) starting xephyr/other X server/specific app on /dev/fb2.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.smsc.com/Products/USB/USB_Graphics_Controllers/UFX7000/Download
they have a link do download their xorg driver, try that

Comment: ah, it's a x.org driver :) anyway they still didn't activated my account and without that I can't download it.